# Elasticsearch: Problem when I try to add dinamically nested objects into filter using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, kibana, .net-8.0

I have a problem when I try to add dynamically nested objects into filter. My query works fine into Kibana but when I translate it into code (I'm using `Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch v8.11.0`) last nested object overwrites the first. Objects are inserted using a `foreach` loop that calls the `GetFacetNestedScope` function.

This is my kibana query:

```
{
  "size": 2000, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "description.title": { "query": "borsa termica", "prefix_length": 1, "fuzziness": "AUTO", "_name": "title" } } },
        { "match": { "description.longDescription": { "query": "borsa termica", "prefix_length": 1, "fuzziness": "AUTO", "_name": "longDescription" } } },
        { "match": { "options.code": { "query": "borsa termica", "prefix_length": 1, "fuzziness": "AUTO", "_name": "code" } } }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "_name": "MARCA_guzzini",
            "path": "erpAttributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "erpAttributes.erpId": {
                      "value": "MARCA"
                    }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "erpAttributes.values",
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "erpAttributes.values.id": {
                          "value": "guzzini"
                        }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
         {
          "nested": {
            "_name": "colore_bianco",
            "path": "erpAttributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "erpAttributes.erpId": {
                      "value": "COL"
                    }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "erpAttributes.values",
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "erpAttributes.values.id": {
                          "value": "bianco"
                        }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "attributi_unici": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "erpAttributes"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nomi_attributi": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "erpAttributes.name",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "valori_unici": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "erpAttributes.values"
              },
              "aggs": {
                
                "id_valori": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "erpAttributes.values.id",
                    "size": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my code (everything is called by `GetQueryFunction`):

```
public static QueryDescriptor<Product> GetQuery(QueryDescriptor<Product> q, IEnumerable<Facet> facets, string searchTerm, string categorySlug)
{
    return q
        .Bool(b =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(categorySlug))
            {
                b.Must(mu => mu
                    .Term(t => t.Field(f => f.Categories.First().Id.Suffix(Constants.ElasticSearch.SuffixKeyword))
                        .Value(categorySlug)));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
            {
                b.Should(
                    sh => GetSearchTermMatchScope(sh, searchTerm,
                        Constants.ElasticSearch.SearchTermFields.Title),
                    sh => GetSearchTermMatchScope(sh, searchTerm,
                        Constants.ElasticSearch.SearchTermFields.LongDescription),
                    sh => GetSearchTermMatchScope(sh, searchTerm,
                        Constants.ElasticSearch.SearchTermFields.Code)
                );
            }

            if (facets != null && facets.Any())
            {
                b.Filter(f =>
                {
                    foreach (var facet in facets)
                    {
                        GetFacetNastedScope(f, facet);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}

public static QueryDescriptor<Product> GetFacetNastedScope(QueryDescriptor<Product> f, Facet facet)
{
    return f.Nested(n => n
        .QueryName(facet.Name)
        .Path(Constants.ElasticSearch.ProductFacetsNastedFields.ErpAttributes)
        .Query(qu => qu
            .Bool(nb => nb
                .Must(m => m
                        .Term(t => t
                            .Field(Constants.ElasticSearch.ProductFacetsNastedFields.ErpAttributesErpId)
                            .Value(facet.Name)
                        ), m => m
                        .Nested(nn => nn
                            .Path(Constants.ElasticSearch.ProductFacetsNastedFields.ErpAttributesValues)
                            .Query(nnq => nnq
                                .Term(t => t
                                    .Field(Constants.ElasticSearch.ProductFacetsNastedFields.ErpAttributesValuesId)
                                    .Value(facet.Value)))
                        )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Documentation for new version of this nuget package is missing and other posts doesn't solve this problem.
Why results are different? Something is missing in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to initialize multiple sub-queries within a single filterdescriptor, create a list of filter descriptors:

```
if (facets != null && facets.Any())
{
    var filterDescriptors = new List<Action<QueryDescriptor<Product>>>();

    foreach (var facet in facets)
    {
        filterDescriptors.Add(f => GetFacetNastedScope(f, facet));
    }

    b.Filter(filterDescriptors.ToArray());
}
```